# Network Service user vanished on IIS7.5 on Windows7

Tags: asp.net, security, iis-7, windows-7, folder-security

I'm installing the ASP .net on Win7, and I need give permission to ASP .net to use the project folder. I have tried Network Service and didn't work; Win7 didn't find that user.

I know that previously the user was ASPNET and later is Network Service, but now, something changed or I'm doing something wrong.  Please help me.

Edit:
*I learn that I can check "My Computer->Manage->Local Users and Groups->Groups->IIS_WPG group.
But that "IIS_WPG" doesn't exists. The group that exists is "IIS_IUSRS", and it dont't have the Network Service user...
I will try reinstall IIS or ASP.Net and check if it works...*

Comment: What local users exist on you machine?  Can you list them?

Comment: @Andrew Hare: Local users are "Administrator", "Guest", "HomeGroupUser" and "ClickOk" (me)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leave the AppPool user as originally configured, so long as you give read/execute permission to the **IIS_WPG** user group. By default, IIS_WPG includes:

- BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS
- NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
- NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
- NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE
- NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

If you don't have an IIS_WPG group, create one and add those accounts.

Answer (score 0):

IIS7 should still be NETWORK SERVICE, however, you can validate this by opening IIS.

Find the APplication pool that you are working with and look to see what user account is associated with the pool.

Comment: Funny, here the AppPool user is "ApplicationPoolIdentity". I changed to NetworkService and I will test if it works